# Bridge a Asynchronous full Duplex TCP communication between 2 listeners

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

**I am in need of a C# layer which will help to exchange the data between two TCP ports which are listening.**

For example, There is a listener port @ 192.168.1.2::5555 and another listener port @ 192.168.1.4::6666.

I am able to establish the connection to both the listeners using socket.connect
I am getting confused during creation of 2 threads
1> Sock1.read()->convert to bytes ->sock2 .write()
2> Sock2.read()->Convert to bytes -> Sock1.write()

I think this is entering into the infinite loop. Is there any better way of exchanging packets between **2 Listening ports** by establishing connection to both ports?

I have to implement a method

```
Private void ExchangePackets(IpEndpoint ipe1,IpEndpoint ipe2)
{
//code here
}
```

Comment: So you have two servers A and B, and a client C. Client C connects to A and to B, then receives data from A, and transmits it to B. Simultaneously client C receives data from B and transmits it to A. Is that correct?

Comment: Right grieve. I am looking out for Async mode of exchange. On using threads, there will be blocking of data.

Comment: @srinivas No there won't, not if you do it properly.

Comment: @L.B I am unable to see the connection between this question and the one you cite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Finally Achieved it :-) $

```
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RoutingClient=new TcpClient("127.0.0.1",5765);
        ServerClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 5766);
        rcStream = RoutingClient.GetStream();
        ScStream = ServerClient.GetStream();
        //start 2 threads
        Thread t1 = new Thread(()=>ExchangePackets(rcStream,ScStream));
        t1.Start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() => ExchangePackets(ScStream, rcStream));
        t2.Start();
    }


    private  static void ExchangePackets(NetworkStream FirstStream, NetworkStream SecondStream)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (FirstStream.CanRead)
                {
                    byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
                    StringBuilder myCompleteMessage = new StringBuilder();
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
                    int TotalBytesRead = 0;
                    // Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size. 
                    do
                    {
                        numberOfBytesRead = FirstStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
                        ms.Write(myReadBuffer, TotalBytesRead, numberOfBytesRead);
                        myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
                        TotalBytesRead = TotalBytesRead + numberOfBytesRead;
                    }
                    while (FirstStream.DataAvailable);
                    MessageBox.Show("You received the following message : " +
                                                 myCompleteMessage);
                    if (SecondStream.CanWrite)
                    {

                        byte[] myWriteBuffer = ms.ToArray();
                        SecondStream.Write(myWriteBuffer, 0, myWriteBuffer.Length);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Sorry.  You cannot write to this NetworkStream.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Sorry.  You cannot read from this NetworkStream.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Routing to Server:" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be something like this:(Not tested)

```
void ExchangePackets(IPEndPoint ipe1, IPEndPoint ipe2)
{
    TcpClient tcp1 = new TcpClient();
    tcp1.Connect(ipe1);

    TcpClient tcp2 = new TcpClient();
    tcp2.Connect(ipe2);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ByPass(tcp1, tcp2), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ByPass(tcp2, tcp1), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}

void ByPass(TcpClient tcp1, TcpClient tcp2)
{
    using (tcp1)
    using (tcp2)
    {
        Stream s1 = tcp1.GetStream();
        Stream s2 = tcp2.GetStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[0x10000];

        int len = s1.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        while (len > 0)
        {
            s2.Write(buf, 0, len);
            len = s1.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: On closer examination, I don't think my answer is suitable for your situation. Your question describes a number of fixed constraints that might prevent you implementing it this way. I will leave my answer here for other people though, as I do think it is generally the right approach.

> Is there any better way of exchanging packets between 2 Listening
>   ports by establishing connection to both ports?

You don't need to reinvent the wheel :)

You can use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) to create a [full-duplex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) service with [TCP transport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx)?